# mysqli query with missing results

Tags: php, mysql, date, select, mysqli

I've created a simple php script, which is running every night and is used to synchronize two databases. For a few days everything seemed to work fine, but today at least one record is missing (I say "at least" because this is the only record that was needed today and was missing from last night).

The workflow of the script is the following:

- Find all records from the first database
- Check which records are needed
- Save the records on the second db

I've found that the problem is the first list query on a table of the first database. I have to extract the record basically from 45 days ago to today and this is the code:

```
$first_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-45 days'));

$first_query = ("SELECT EVERYTHING_I_NEED
    FROM mytable table1
    WHERE table1.FileName IS NOT NULL
    AND table1.creation_date > DATE_FORMAT('" . $first_date . "','%Y%m%d')");

$list = mysqli_query($_CONFIG['conn'], $first_query);
```

Now... I extract something about 12k records every night and that's another data in favor of the to the "at least" one record is missing.

**Tricky part:**

I suppose that the error is on the query's date check part:

```
table1.creation_date > DATE_FORMAT('" . $first_date . "','%Y%m%d')")
```

because, unfortunately for me, who created this first database table has setted "creation_date" as a `CHAR(8)`... I've tried to run the script again with some more logs and the problem is that there are many other records like the one missing, and mostly with the same data as this one (so created the same day but with different file name).
Please tell me if I have to be more precise.

Am I missing something or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't understand why you create your `$first_date` in the `Y-m-d` format and then reformat it with SQL in to `Ymd`.

Comment: My fault... Copy/paste error... I'll edit it

Comment: Is the missing record possibly at either the start or end of the 45 days?

Comment: It could be something data-related. Check the creation_date and FileName of the record that's missing, and compare it to your query. Also run the above query  in mysql directly while adding a specific record ID to see if you get the record

Comment: Sorry, what format is creation_date? What's the problem with assigning it a proper data type?

Comment: @Strawberry, as I understand it `creation_date` is a CHAR(8) in the format "YYYYMMDD". I guess OP doesn't want to migrate it and in theory it should still be comparable as a string.

Comment: DaveK no... As I wrote the other records of the same day are present... @aynber I've already done the check also adding **AND id=xxx**, the record comes out... So I tried to extract only the records of the day and is missing

Comment: @IlGala, that's very odd. Adding a conjunct should certainly not find any records that weren't present without the conjunct.

Comment: Sorry I've made an error... I've relaunched the query checking for creation_date >= **missing data day** and the record comes out... With creation_date >= **-45 days from today** it doesn't